# Spyder crashes in Manjaro KDE

Tags: python, pyqt5, spyder, pyside, pyside2

Spyder crashes in Manjaro KDE with the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qtpy/__init__.py", line 204, in <module>
    from PySide import __version__ as PYSIDE_VERSION  # analysis:ignore
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/spyder3", line 3, in <module>
    start.main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spyder/app/start.py", line 200, in main
    from spyder.app import mainwindow
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 54, in <module>
    requirements.check_qt()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spyder/requirements.py", line 41, in check_qt
    import qtpy
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qtpy/__init__.py", line 210, in <module>
    raise PythonQtError('No Qt bindings could be found')
qtpy.PythonQtError: No Qt bindings could be found
```

PyQt5 and PySide are already installed and I still get the error. I already tried installing other spyder versions in pamac and pip but got the same error.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the python that is being used isn't the one from anaconda:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qtpy/__init__.py"
```

Try doing the following:

Inside your terminal write:

// this will deactivate the base environment

// you will need to: "conda reactivate" later to use spyder again

```
conda deactivate
```

then do:

```
pip install PyQt5 PySide
```

then:

```
conda activate

spyder
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't have anaconda installed. As you have said, I am running Spyder independently.

Comment: Also, when I install PySide using pip, I get the following error:
`ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-5isuaumb/PySide/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-5isuaumb/PySide/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-gs1r79jt`

Comment: `cwd: /tmp/pip-install-5isuaumb/PySide/
    Complete output (1 lines):
    only these python versions are supported: [(2, 6), (2, 7), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4)]
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.`

Comment: Which version of Spyder do you have? Try this: pip install PySide2
You may also need to install this: https://build-system.fman.io/qt-designer-download